# Putting Paypal ASP.Net SDK code Live

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I have used the ASP.Net sample code in a website. All works fine when using the sandbox, but I can't work out the correct settings to put it live.

In the constants.cs file this setting is 'sandbox' for test, but what should it be when going live?

```
public const string ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox";
```

It is used in ReviewOrder.cs to construct the Paypal Url:

```
                string host = "www." + Session["stage"].ToString() + ".paypal.com";
```

I can hardcode the URL and get the application working, but I would rather understand the code before I put it live.
Anyone used the paypal SDK code samples?

Comment: I think you can just set it to "live". I think it is only in the instance of the `ENVIRONMENT` being "sandbox" or "beta-sandbox" that the API End Point is changed from its default. As in `(if sandbox) { sandbox endpoint} (else) {default [live] endpoint}` Is there no conditional statement prior to your 2nd line of provided code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal have confirmed this is a bug in the SDK sample code.  The workaround for anyone who needs it is:

```
string host = "www.paypal.com";
```